# Single Complement Variable + 1

Tags: boolean-algebra

Is a complement + 1 = 1? For example A' + 1 = 0;

I was thinking it was (I'm new to boolean algebra) since A' = 0, and 0 + 1 in boolean algebra is just 1. Of course, A can be anything, but assuming this is a single variable like B being represented as A, compared to ABCD being represented as A.

Comment: What do the axioms say is the value of $x+1$ for _any_ $x$?

Comment: Dilip, x + 1 = 1 for any x. But doesn't the x have to be non-complement? Or can x even be complements?

Comment: No, that is for **any** $x$ in the algebra.

Comment: Sorry, Brian not sure I follow. "No" to what?

Comment: If it makes you feel better, begin your proof with the statement: "Let $x$ denote $A^\prime$.  Then, since $x+1=1$ by Axiom $\cdots$, we have that $A^\prime+1=1$."

Comment: Dilip, if I can specify whether x is complement or non-complement, then why do some laws specify X', such as DeMorgan's Law: X'Y' = X' + Y'?

Comment: Please re-read Demorgan's Laws **very carefully**.  Does one of them _really_ say $X^\prime Y^\prime = X^\prime + Y^\prime$ as you contend, or does it say $(XY)^\prime = X^\prime + Y^\prime$ ??

Comment: You asked whether $x$ had to a non-complement; I answered ‘No’. (You need to precede a name with '@' in order to ensure that the person sees your comment. I saw yours only because I checked back on a whim.)

Answer (score 1):

Answered in the comments: yes, (something) + 1 = 1 in a Boolean algebra. It does not matter if (something) was obtained as a complement of an element, or in another way. Dilip Sarwate made a good suggestion:

> If it makes you feel better, begin your proof with the statement: "Let $x$ denote $A'$. Then, since $x+1=1$ by Axiom $\dots$, we have that $A'+1=1$."